# How to Use WordNet::Similarity module?

Tags: perl

I want to compare multiple sentences and find out the similarity between them. I have installed the WordNet::Similarity module. But I am not getting any way to how to use it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose to use a module the bare minimum you need to do is read the documentation. There is a section called [Typical usage examples](http://search.cpan.org/~tpederse/WordNet-Similarity-2.05/lib/WordNet/Similarity.pm#Typical_Usage_Examples). Other than that the distribution itself has [examples](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/TPEDERSE/WordNet-Similarity-2.05/samples/) included.